# How can I stop my Ubuntu netbook from un-suspending while the lid's closed?

Tags: ubuntu, netbook

Almost every time I want to use my netbook, it's un-suspended itself because the button is too easy to press.

Is there some way to tell Ubuntu (Netbook Remix 10.04) NOT to un-suspend if the lid's closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fashioned a physical button-guard out of a bottle-cap. it sits over the hinge (where the button was) and is held in place by the 2 faces of the netbook...

Answer (score 1):

Guess it's not possible since it's a pure ACPI function. (Only things like when to suspend you can set. Try checking the BIOS though, there is an option like "Wake up to..." keyboard and so on. Usually.